# $X^2+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{R}$[X] without using $\leq$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}$  be a field.
Show that $X^2+1\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ is irreducible.

I have a proof in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and therefore in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, by showing $(X+1)^2+1$ is irreducible by Eisenstein’s Criterion (And then by Gauss’ Lemma).

How would I prove in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ **without** using $\leq$.

I’ve run into problems because $\mathbb{R}$ has no primes (as all the elements are zero or units), and am struggling to prove that $x^2+1\neq 0$ for all x (ie proof by it having no roots).

Thanks for any help

EDIT: I think the formatting must be off somewhere, but seems fine on my screen. All I don’t want to use is the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is an **ordered** field. I have no problem with solutions using an equals sign

Comment: $x^2+1=(x-a)(x-b)$ if possible implies $a+b=0$ and $ab=-1$. Show that these conditions are not valid for real numbers.

Comment: You have used $=$. It said, without using $<$ or $=$. And $ab=1$ with $b=-a$ again amounts to $a^2<0$, which we are not allowed.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Why is that so?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : It should be $ab=1$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran True, but the question stands.

Comment: My bad meant R, will update

Comment: @SaucyO'Path : In that case, $(a+b)^2=0\implies a^2+b^2=-2$ which is not possible as $a^2\geq0\;\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran Again, why is $a^2+b^2=-2$ not possible? Because squares cannot be negative? But this is not allowed to use, e.g., $a^2\ge 0$ is forbidden to use.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot prove something like $x^2+1\neq 0$ without using $=$, or $\ge$, because that is just the question. This is like asking "Show that $3$ does not divide $2^n$ **without** using divisibility.

$x^2+1=0$ has no solution in any ordered field. I think we need to use that $\Bbb R$ is an ordered field in order to show that $x^2+1$ has no real root.

Answer (score -1):

$x^2+1\in\mathbb{R}[x]\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x]$ as $\mathbb{R}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. So it makes sense to use the evalutaion map $\phi_i:\mathbb{C}[x]\to\mathbb{C}$. From this we see that $x^2+1$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$,  which is $\textit{purely imaginary}$.

Comment: If $x^2+1=0$, then $x-a$ and $x-b$ are no longer polynomials. We cannot assume that $x^2+1$ is the zero polynomial. One has degree $2$, the other not.

Comment: The OP already knows that $X^2+1$ is irreducible. He wants to prove that $x^2+1\neq 0$ for all real numbers $x$ without using that the real numbers are an ordered field.